# Where can I learn more about end point management with Snappy Ubuntu Core?

Tags: landscape, ubuntu-core

Where can I learn more about end point management with snappy Ubuntu Core?  Meaning, how would one go about managing both the OS and the snaps on multiple machines? Is Landscape the answer? I couldn't find it specifically called out on the site.

Also in general how is it built? Same as Desktop?

https://landscape.canonical.com/try-landscape

Comment: You can find more information on this at a similar [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816118/managing-large-scale-snappy-core-iot-deployment).